# Include jquery in angularjs controller

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have an angularjs partial template that includes a datepicker. I use jquery's datepicker. I have referenced the required jquery cdn in the main `index.html` and the following code to show a datepicker on click of a input field:

`$("#inputTxt").datepicker()`.

I can get the datepicker in a full `index.html` without any templates

I have this and reference to jquery in the `index.html`  and not in the template.html. I can't get the datepicker to popup in  the template. How to do this. I'm new to angularjs and I don't know how exactly I should do this. Please help

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
  $("#inputTxt").datepicker();
</script>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/userCtrl.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/datepicker.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="public/javascripts/deviceMasterCtrl.js">
    </script>


</head>
<body ng-app="empApp">
```

Comment: Your `$("inputTxt").datepicker()` is in your template ? Under `<script>` tag ?

Comment: In your index.html, you should reference Jquery BEFORE angularJS

Comment: @Weedoze.  yeah. thats how it is..i added the jquery(`$("#inputTxt").datepicker()`) along with the reference to cdn in the `index.html` and then tried it in `template.html`. It still isn't working. When I add the code in the `index.html`, I get `datepicker() is not a funciton`

Comment: Please add index.html in your question

Comment: @Weedoze. i've posted it

Comment: You are referencing 2 times JQuery

Comment: @Nobody - because template.html takes some time to bind, so by that time your DOM is not ready and does not contain the element with `id="inputTxt"`, whereas `$("inputTxt").datepicker()` is already executed without the element, you should use directive if you want to use jQuery or use this for datepicker - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker